# ffmpeg watermarking processing is very slow

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, watermark

I am working on a video processing project and using ffmpeg for watermarking. I achieve exactly what i want but the problem is that the process is very very slow.

I am using a Intel Smart 2nd gen family Core-i5 Processor with 4GB RAM on a 32 bit operating system Microsoft Windows-8 on a 64-bit CPU.

I tried watermarking a video [mp4] of length 1:30 Min. size of file is 1.5GB

Whole process accomplish in 3 Hrs to watermark my video file and what i noticed while process is that ffmpeg was processing 28 frames per sec first and then later it slow down up to 20 frames per second. a normal human watch video with frame rate of 30 frame per second and process was even slower then this that's why it took more time [3 Hrs] then the actual length of video itself [1:33]

What i think to make process efficient is to use ffmpeg Watermarking [Source Code](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.5/watermark_8c-source.html) and modify it somewhat...

I want to ask if someone have achieve fast watermarking before by any other way or have modified this code to achieve faster process in order to save my time...

Comment: What's the frame size? It sounds a bit slow but I don't think FFMpeg utilizes hardware support (for MP4 via GPU) which could explain the lack of speed if the frame size is large. You can perhaps config it to use an external codec that do support hardware.. This may be useful: http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/how-to-enable-hardware-acceleration-in-ffmpeg-td4438476.html

Comment: Did you able to speed it up?

Comment: No, I use a different method of watermarking. I embed watermarking in software to show it on video instead of watermarking whole video through ffmpeg. It was easy and quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed up you might try to skip middle frames like apply watermark on next 5th frame if that number dont create flickr

Comment: hmmm didn't think about that. You may leave command here for other users. It may be helpful.

Comment: Hi were you able to fix this issue? if so what was your ffmpeg command?

Comment: Well, It didn't work for me as expected. I tried a different method. I make a watermarking widget in software that I set on always on top mode. I changed its position randomly after every few minutes and that saved a lot of my effort.