# watermarking to video Android using ffmpeg

Tags: android, kotlin, watermark, android-ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I am using ffmpeg library for water marking in android, somehow it is taking high amount of time (like 5MB video taking 1 minute of time). Let me know if you have any suggestions.

gradle dependency: `implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'`

slow code: `val command = arrayOf("-i", srcVideo, "-i", watermarkImgPath, "-filter_complex", "overlay=20:20", outPutVideo)`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589904/ffmpeg-adding-image-watermark-to-video-process-is-very-slow/55598421

Comment: { "-i",inputPath.mp4, "-i", imagepath.jpg,"-filter_complex", "[1] scale=70:70 [tmp];[0][tmp] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10",output.mp4} try this it will help you.

Comment: @VikasSharmalp i use the same line in my code, every thing is correct but in the end the error are occur, and the error is
`Error Creating Video`
`Command failed with state COMPLETED and rc 1.null`

Comment: i don't know what thing is wrong when all requirement of code i given
my code is:-
`{"-i", new_vid, "-i", String.valueOf(bit), "-filter_complex", "[1] scale=70:70 [tmp];[0][tmp] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10", newfiles};`

Answer (score 0):

try using this implementation: `implementation 'com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-full-gpl:4.5.1-1'`